# ROS2 - Does ros1_bridge suppports Indigo

Tags: ros, ros2, ardent, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I am currently working on a ROS system which has Indigo Distribution. And will be migrating to ROS2 soon.

I would like to know if the `ros1_bridge` supports **ROS1 Indigo** distribution.

In the official Github page I could not find details regarding the support to different distribution.

Thank you
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324778/ros2---does-ros1_bridge-suppports-indigo/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2019-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since Indigo targets Ubuntu Trusty and ROS 2 only targets Ubuntu Bionic (or Ubuntu Xenial for older releases) there is no platform overlap between the two. So no, the `ros_bridge` doesn't support ROS 1 Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2019-06-06**:
Thanks for the swift response and clarification. My problem statement has become more complicated now. :-(

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-06-06**:
Please consider to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark left of the answer if it addressed your question. That will help others to find this answered question.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2019-06-11**:
@Dirk Thomas Yep. It is done. Thanks for the help. :-)